# How to update a property using Type.GetProperties() method?

Tags: c#-3.0

I've a collection of a class' properties and would like to update each one's value by iterating over the collection through the index.

1) I create the collection of properties this way

```
private PropertyInfo[] GetPropertiesOfMyClass()
    {
        Type myType = (typeof(myClass));
        PropertyInfo[] PropertyInfoArray = myType.GetProperties(
                                                BindingFlags.Public |
                                                BindingFlags.Instance);
        return PropertyInfoArray;                 
    }
```

2)Now, I'd like to set up the value of each one depending on the index this way

```
    public void UpdateProperty(MyClass instanceOfMyClass, string valueToUpdate, int index)
    {
      //TODO:
      //1. Get an individual property from the GetPropertyOfMyClass() using index
      //2. Update the value of an individual property of the instanceOfMyClass
    }
```

I'd like to be able to call **UpdateProperty** from a Controller like this:

```
UpdateProperty(instanceOfMyClass, valueToUpdate, indexOfTheProperty);
```

Honestly, I do not know how to involve the **instanceOfMyClass** in the game as **GetProperty** only plays with **myClass**.

Since I saw that I can use Name, PropertyType, ... to get information on the property. So, I've tried also **GetPropertyOfMyClass()[index].SetValue(...)**, but I was lost in the arguments of its constructor, so I abandoned.

What I want is to be able to update the value of a property in my collection just by using the index.

Thanks for helping

Comment: Keep in mind, that reflection is quite expensive. Instead of calling `GetPropertyOfMyClass()` again and again you might want to cache the results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your guess was correct. You use `SetValue()` to update the value - this is how to do it:

```
GetPropertyOfMyClass()[index].SetValue( instanceOfMyClass, valueToUpdate, null);
```

The last argument [can be null](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xb5dd1f1.aspx):

> Optional index values for indexed properties. This value should be null for non-indexed properties.